# How to map JSON object to subclass entity?

Tags: java, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

If I have a supertype and a subtype entity like so:

```
public class Eyes {
    // attributes
    String someAttribute;

    // default construct

    // getters/setters
}

public abstract class Animal {
    // attributes
    Eyes eyes;
    String name;

    // default construct

    // getters/setters
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    // attributes
    Something something;
    String x;

    // default construct

    // getters/setters
}
```

I also have an endpoint to create an Animal of type Dog:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public void createDog(Dog dog) {...}
```

I then initiate a post request like so:

```
{
    "dog": {
        "something": {...}, 
        "x": "awd",
        "eyes": { <- problem
            "someAttribute": "some string"
        },
        "name": "Devi"
    }
}
```

I receive an error while execute this request of this JSON body:

> jakarta.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "api.entity.Eyes.getSomeAttribute()" because the return value of "api.entity.Dog.getEyes()" is null

I am unsure if it is how I formatted my JSON that results in this error or something else. Not too sure how jsonb handles creating objects in abstract types. Setting name results in no errors in Animal. Just the Eyes are the problem when trying to set someAttribute.

Comment: We don't know when getEyes() is being called. It sounds odd to me that the serializer would call any getXxx() when DEserializing. Usually the setters are called when deserializing. As an aside, I would switch to using Jackson as the provider.

Comment: That would be in my actual method. So I invoke dog.getEyes().getSomeAttribute(). But this is null. So it did not deserialize correctly, possibly because the structure of my JSON is incorrect.

Comment: I don't know how JSONB works, but with other serializers, they call the setters to populate the values. If your setters aren't named correctly, then it can't be called. Is the name value set correctly?

Comment: My mistake, I am using Jackson (3.0.3) to be specific. I have setters and getters for all of them. They are default, so dog.getEyes() returns Eyes, which can be null if not set. Which is not setting if I keep getting a null for trying to getEyes(). Hence why I think my JSON is incorrectly formatted or something.

Comment: You should not have the outer object in the JSON unless you configure Jackson to use "wrapped" objects.